# Did Starfleet ever have an Enterprise-class of starship?

Tags: star-trek

The Star Trek series has many different classes of star ships featured in the shows and movies. Some examples include: Constitution-class, Galaxy-class, Excelsior-class, Intrepid-class, Defiant-class and Sovereign-class. But never have I seen or heard reference to any Enterprise-class ships.

Starfleet ship classes are usually named after the first prototype vessel of that class made; i.e. the first Galaxy-class vessel would have been named the USS Galaxy. And as prototype vessels usually have NX- designations that leads me to believe that the class of ships seen in the show *Enterprise* would be of an Enterprise-class, if the design was ever put into production. But as far I am aware that never happened in canon and the NX-01 Enterprise was referred to as a NX-class ship on the show.

To sum up then, has Starfleet ever had an Enterprise class of star ship?

Comment: ["Lead ship"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead_ship) is the naval term for "first prototype vessel of that class".

Comment: Perhaps there will be a Kirk-class starship.

Comment: As a nitpick, the class is named after the ship, not the other way around.

Comment: @bishop That would be for most navies, the Royal Navy mostly follows this, but there are some discrepancies in a few classes. The HMS Invincible was the last (third) of [her class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invincible-class_battlecruiser#Construction) to be laid down, second to be launched, and last to be commissioned.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## No, not in canon.

In canon, there has never been an Enterprise-class starship in Starfleet.

**But a lesser-known fact is that the decision for the Enterprises NCC-1701 and NCC-1701-A to be "Constitution class" was not made until 1987.**  Before that time, no class designation was given in dialogue in *TOS* or the films before that year.  Prior to 1987, both "Starship class" and "Enterprise class" were used informally amongst Star Trek creative personnel to describe the original Enterprise, and "Starship class" appears on the bridge dedication plaque on the NCC-1701.  ("Enterprise class" was specifically floated by Andrew Probert for the refit Enterprise in *The Motion Picture*, but this idea was dropped.)

Also, in the original script for *The Wrath of Khan*, the Reliant was described as "Enterprise class", and indeed the ship was intended to be a copy of the Enterprise.  However, it was decided at the design stage to fundamentally change the shape of the Reliant in order to better distinguish the two ships in battle.  Later, the Reliant was retconned as "Miranda class".

For a history of the complicated evolution of "Constitution class" from "Enterprise class", with reliable citations and direct quotes by Enterprise designer Andrew Probert, see [here](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Enterprise_class).

Comment: _Constitution_-class goes back as far as 1966. Memory Alpha: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Constitution_class#footnote_1 .  It also appeared in the 1975 _Star Fleet Technical Manual_.

Comment: @Spencer : But the term "Consitution class" in 1966 was not necessarily describing the Enterprise.  Roddenberry and Probert themselves did not use the term, preferring "Starship class".

Comment: In context, the 1966 "Space Seed" reference pretty clearly puts Enterprise in the Constitution class: Khan - "I would be most interested in studying the tech manual on your vessel..." Kirk - "They are available on your viewing screen there." Khan needed to know about Enterprise in particular and wouldn't have any reason to study other Federation ship classes at that time. (Probert wasn't involved in TOS, by the way; he came on for Phase II and TMP.)

Comment: @RussellBorogove : I say it's unclear because on the dedication plaque in the same episode, it says "Starship Class".  "Constitution Class" was to appear in one library tape panel viewed by Khan, but was ultimately not used in the episode.  Indeed, Probert wasn't involved in *TOS*, but was instrumental in the transition from *TOS* to *Phase II* when the issue of ship "class" was revisited, and "Constitution Class" was not an option on the table.

Comment: Nevertheless, it's incorrect to say that the term didn't appear until 1987. And before we start counting angels dancing on pins, I'm signing off.

Comment: @Spencer: I agree, but just to be clear, that's not what I wrote.  What I said was: "But a lesser-known fact is that the *decision* for the Enterprises NCC-1701 and NCC-1701-A to be "Constitution class" was not made until 1987. Before that time, no class designation was given in *dialogue* in TOS or the films before that year."

Comment: @Praxis, only counting if it's stated in dialogue is somewhat limiting and can be ridiculous. Using that definition, the *Excelsior* Class *Enterprise* didn't have the designation NCC-1701-B, nor did the *Sovereign* Class one have the designation NCC-1701-E because neither was stated in dialogue. They're in really big text on the hulls in clear view, but no one *said* that (that I can recall), so using the dialogue only criteria, those aren't canon. Which seems a bit silly.

Comment: @KeithMorrison : I'm not sure what you're going on about.  It's already clear that "Constitution Class" does not appear on the original Enterprise 1701, neither on the hull nor on the bridge dedication plaque, which is why we have this question in the first place.  Before 1987, it doesn't appear in any supporting materials, including the 1975 *Starfleet Technical Manual*.  That leaves dialogue and scripts. I did tremendous research and was able to turn up anecdotes of how production personnel referred to the class and script notes from *Wrath* about the Reliant being "Enterprise class".

Comment: @KeithMorrison : You can read my answer how you like, but I'm not defining the class by "only counting if it's stated in dialogue", or that canon is "only dialogue".  I'm only saying it's not mentioned in dialogue.  Your interpretation of my answer is extreme.

Comment: @Praxis - I have the 1975 technical manual, and it does in fact list the TOS Enterprise as being a Constitution-class Heavy Cruiser, based on the organization of the page. I'm not where my copy of the technical manual is, so I can't cite page and provide description, but this is something that I am _absolutely_ certain of.

Answer (score 15):

### Yes (at least in the EU).

The [James Blish novelisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_(Blish)) of [TOS: Charlie X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlie_X) includes the following passage:

> For a moment, the screen showed nothing but a scan of stars, fading
>   into faint nebulosity in the background. Then, suddenly, the strange
>   ship was there. Superficially, **it looked much like an Enterprise-class
>   starship; a domed disc, seemingly coming at the screen nearly edge-on-
>   though of course it was actually approaching the satellite, not the
>   Enterprise.** Its size, however, was impossible to guess without a
>   distance estimate.
>
> “Full magnification, Lieutenant Uhura.”

Obviously this conflicts with *later* (TV) canon that indicates that the ship is 'Constitution-Class', but at the time there was no reason to assume this was not correct.

---

Similarly, the Star Trek RPG (FASA Ship Recognition Manual) makes extensive reference to an "Enterprise Class". This was, however corrected in later versions when the main canon conflicted with their interpretation.

[image]

Comment: Also [this](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Enterprise_class_%2823rd_century%29) and [this](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Enterprise_class_%28alternate_future%29), unless you already covered one of those in your answer.

Comment: @amaranth - I'm on it, like a bonnet

Answer (score 7):

## Yes, in the Mark IV bridge simulator

No Enterprise-class ships were built in canon (see the [list of starship classes](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Federation_starship_classes) at Memory Alpha), but according to the [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Trek-II-The-Wrath-of-Khan.html) of *The Wrath of Khan*, the [Mark IV bridge simulator](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mark_IV_bridge_simulator) used at Starfleet Academy simulated an *Enterprise*-class starship. The simulator was apparently programed to simulate a fictitious ship that was very similar to a *Constitution*-class starship.

Comment: Just to be accurate: it was never referred to on-screen as "Enterprise class", only in the script notes.

Comment: @Praxis Did they ever indicate the class of the ship on-screen? Because if not, I think it's fair to go with the script. The ship in the simulator doesn't have to be real.

Comment: It's definitely fair, and I'm glad you restored your answer.  I just thought it would be good to indicate where exactly the reference to the class is (which you've done).  :-)

Comment: @Praxis Well, my answer was kind of nonsense before. I should probably edit in some sort of credit to you for the script reference, since I only found it after reading your answer.

Comment: Nah, it's all good.  Let's just all rejoice in the multitude of Trek info we're collecting.  :-)

Comment: @Praxis Is that part of the script even describing the simulator? I can't tell. Maybe I should just put in the DVD tonight. I hope this answer isn't wrong again...

Comment: There are definitely production notes that describe the simulator room as an "Enterprise-class bridge".  I think you're fine. :-)